# How do the various programs read or write integrals in FCIDUMP format?

Tags: software, electronic-structure, one-topic-per-answer, integrals, fcidump

The `FCIDUMP` format was [created by Peter Knowles and Nick Handy *circa* 1989](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0010465589900337?via%3Dihub) and now allows many electronic structure software packages to interact with each other.

For example imagine we want to calculate the 1- and 2-electron integrals with [OpenMOLCAS](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.jctc.9b00532) (likely the fastest and most general open-source software for calculating integrals) then run a rather special electronic structure method like FCIQMC with those integrals (FCIQMC is best done with the [NECI software](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/5.0005754) written mainly by the people that invented and developed FCIQMC). In this case the integrals will be calculated in OpenMOLCAS, printed to an `FCIDUMP` file, then the software NECI will read the integrals from that file.

The following programs are able to interact with `FCIDUMP` files in some way:

- **MOLPRO**  (can read and write)
- **PySCF** (can read and write)
- **(Open)MOLCAS** (can write)
- **ARROW** (can read and modify)
- **DALTON** (can write)
- **DIRAC** (can write)
- **GAMESS** (can write, with a plug-in)
- **DICE** (can read and maybe modify)
- **BLOCK** (can read and maybe modify)
- **CheMPS2** (can read and maybe modify)
- **xacc** (can read)
- *anymore you wish to add*

The following can interact with the standard `FCIDUMP` format of 1989, but can also support generalizations of it:

- **NECI** (can read, and modify standard `FCIDUMP` files, and can write some 3-body integrals)
- **BAGEL** (can write complex-valued integrals for 4-component relativistic calculations)
- **HANDE** (can include more 1-electron integrals, including orbital energies, can list UHF/RHF)
- **Psi4** (supports the generalized format of HANDE)

For some of these programs, like MOLPRO, `FCIDUMP` format is supported **natively** and it's quite straightforward to figure out how to read/write `FCIDUMP` files, by browsing the software's manual. However other programs need an extra plug-in, and/or have some caveats, and/or require slightly non-trivial work to grease the wheels to support `FCIDUMP` formatted integrals, and/or the support is not explained in the manual. **In these cases, how does one read or write integrals in `FCIDUMP` format?**

(Please write only one answer per software package).

Answer (score 3):

## Psi4

[Psi4](https://psicode.org/psi4manual/master/introduction.html#) provides functions for [reading](https://psicode.org/psi4manual/master/api/psi4.driver.fcidump.html) and [writing](https://psicode.org/psi4manual/master/api/psi4.driver.fcidump_from_file.html#psi4.driver.fcidump_from_file) FCIDUMP files from wavefunction objects. Using Psi4 as a Python module, these look something like:

```
import psi4

#Writing (default fname is "INTDUMP")
E, wfn = psi4.energy('scf', return_wfn=True)
psi4.fcidump(wfn)

#Reading
##Returns dict of numerous properties including 1e ("hcore") and 2e ("eri") integrals
values=psi4.fcidump_from_file("INTDUMP")
```